# How to query to Elasticsearch in Grafana

Tags: database, elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I have the following data in **Elasticsearch**.(Since data is a little bit long, I've attached it at the bottom.) I am trying to figure out how to query in order to show something on a graph in **Grafana**.

I know my data in elasticsearch is not suitable for graphs, but I don't have any other sample data, and I just want to learn how to work this query. I've done something like this with **mysql and grafana**. (The data wasn't suitable for a graph, but I managed to make it like the below image) 
[image: Mysql and Grafana]

I want to do the above with Elasticsearch. Since they use **Lucene** query(different from Mysql), I read some information on that. But I have no clues on what to put where. I want to show maybe **metascore**, or **votes** (please look at the **Json** at the bottom) on a graph.

[image: Elasticsearch and Grafana]

I used Postman.
[image]
Here is the JSON type data. (I want to use 'votes' or 'metascore' to appear on the graph)

```
{
    "took": 113,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 8,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "dzb6AGoBnuCYnlTWZNmc",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Justice League",
                    "genre": "Action",
                    "summary": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy",
                    "yearofrelease": 201,
                    "metascore": 45,
                    "votes": 275122,
                    "rating": 6.6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Justice League1",
                    "genre": "Action1",
                    "summary": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy",
                    "yearofrelease": 201,
                    "metascore": 45,
                    "votes": 275122,
                    "rating": 6.6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Justice League",
                    "genre": "Action",
                    "summary": "Fueled by his restored faith in humanity and inspired by Superman's selfless act, Bruce Wayne enlists the help of his newfound ally, Diana Prince, to face an even greater enemy",
                    "yearofrelease": 2011,
                    "metascore": 45,
                    "votes": 275122,
                    "rating": 6.6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "hDYYAWoBnuCYnlTWyNmZ",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Thor Ragnarok",
                    "genre": "Action",
                    "summary": "Thor is imprisoned on the planet Sakaar, and must race  against time to return to Asgard and stop Ragnarök, the destruction of his world, at the hands of the powerful and ruthless villain Hela",
                    "yearofrelease": 2017,
                    "metascore": 74,
                    "votes": 374270,
                    "rating": 7.9
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "hTYYAWoBnuCYnlTWyNmZ",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Infinity War",
                    "genre": "Sci-Fi",
                    "summary": "The Avengers and their allies must be willing to sacrifice all in an attempt to defeat the powerful Thanos before his blitz of devastation and ruin puts an end to the universe",
                    "yearofrelease": 2018,
                    "metascore": 68,
                    "votes": 450856,
                    "rating": 8.6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "hzYYAWoBnuCYnlTW-9mV",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Thor Ragnarok",
                    "genre": "Action",
                    "summary": "Thor is imprisoned on the planet Sakaar, and must race  against time to return to Asgard and stop Ragnarök, the destruction of his world, at the hands of the powerful and ruthless villain Hela",
                    "yearofrelease": 2017,
                    "metascore": 74,
                    "votes": 374270,
                    "rating": 7.9
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "iDYYAWoBnuCYnlTW-9mV",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Infinity War",
                    "genre": "Sci-Fi",
                    "summary": "The Avengers and their allies must be willing to sacrifice all in an attempt to defeat the powerful Thanos before his blitz of devastation and ruin puts an end to the universe",
                    "yearofrelease": 2018,
                    "metascore": 68,
                    "votes": 450856,
                    "rating": 8.6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "movies",
                "_type": "movie",
                "_id": "iTYYAWoBnuCYnlTW-9mV",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Christopher Robin",
                    "genre": "Comedy",
                    "summary": "A working-class family man, Christopher Robin, encounters his childhood friend Winnie-the-Pooh, who helps him to  rediscover the joys of life",
                    "yearofrelease": 2018,
                    "metascore": 60,
                    "votes": 9648,
                    "rating": 7.9
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If this data is impossible to be displayed on a graph, then could you give me some tips on what I can put in the query and metric fields below so that I can work this when I have other sample data. I need an example like 'metascore' should go in this field, and you need  @ or _ and put index here, and type there, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

First, you need to go to Data Sources in **Grafana**, and **choose Elasticsearch**.

[image: Data sources]

[image]
You put your **index** name here. And most importantly, you need a field that can tell time. I used date field. I made a simple sample data like the below. (Look at the **date** field.)
[image: sample]

Go to Grafana dashboard. And in the query, you will see that **Date Histogram** will be automatically set to **date**. Choose the metric that you want.

[image]

You will see something like this on your graph.

[image]

I know my data, field, and so on is not ideal graph material. But I focused on how, not what. Please think of this as 'hello world' for Elastic and Grafana. Hope this helps someone and save their time and energy.